# lua_pop vs lua_remove

Tags: c++, c, lua

Currently I'm building my own script VM manager class in C++. I have no problems with any of the Lua & Lua C or C++ stuff, but the one section that confuses me is when to use `lua_pop` and when to use `lua_remove`.

From what I understand, `lua_pop` is to remove multiple values(on the stack) from the top down, eliminating data that is no longer needed, where as `lua_remove` is for removing a single value from any arbitrary, valid stack index (basically what the Lua manual says for both :P).

But I've noticed certain segments of code scattered around the web that intermix `lua_pop` and `lua_remove`, but when I tried to use `lua_pop` instead of `lua_remove` where the call just removed the top stack element, I ran into problems. So would it be possible to get a definitive example or explanation on how and when to use these two functions correctly, as well as relative speed & efficiency for these two? I assume `lua_pop` is faster than `lua_remove`, which is one of the reasons why I want to use `lua_pop` as much as possible, apart from coding 'correct code'.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. 

"coding 'correct code'"

is *way* more important.

Comment: well I like to get it correct, so that I can then optimize away when its done

Comment: optimize only after your code works and optimization is clearly and measurably needed. There's no point having more complexity and higher maintenance costs just to show off.

Comment: agreed, I don't have time to waste going through the generated assembly to see where a can gain a few cycles with minor tweaks (I save that for when I'm really bored ;)), this is why I'm asking this though, my code works flawlessly, but working flawlessly doesn't mean its entirely correct, so, first point was to check if its correct, if either way is correct, check the second point, which was to check if there is any gain in using x func over y func, if its worth it, implement it, else leave a note in the source for future reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A typical example of `lua_remove` is accessing tables. Snippets from [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

```
lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "t");   /* table to be indexed */
lua_getfield(L, -1, "x");        /* push result of t.x (2nd arg) */
lua_remove(L, -2);                  /* remove 't' from the stack */
```

lua_getfield pushes t[x] on the stack. You no longer need t, so you remove it.

A typical example of `lua_pop` is iterating over a table.

```
lua_pushnil(L);  /* first key */
while (lua_next(L, t) != 0) {
    /* uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1) */
    /* do whatever you like with the key and the value */

    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

After you are done with a single iteration, you need to have the key on top of the stack, so that `lua_next` knows which key/value pair comes next. You need to remove the value, which is on top of the stack.

It's not a definitive example. In Lua you do whatever works for you. Always keep in mind what's on your lua_State stack, and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks I'll look into the tables section again and see if that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

They are very different. `lua_pop` always removes from the top of the stack.  `lua_remove` will remove a value from anywere on the stack.  If the value you wish to remove from the stack is not on the top you can't use `lua_pop`.

e.g.

```
[5][4][3][2][1]
after lua_pop(L, 3); would be
[X][X][X][2][1]



[5][4][3][2][1]
after lua_remove(L, 3); would be
[X][5][4][2][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following pieces of C code are entirely equivalent:

```
lua_pop(L, 1); // same as:
lua_remove(L, -1);
```

So are these:

```
lua_pop(L, n); // same as:
lua_settop(L, lua_gettop(L)-n);
```